# Messages in terminal loading file_name.dll failed OpenCV VSCode

Tags: c++, windows, opencv, visual-studio-code

I have some issue with running opencv "hello world". The code runs successfully that it displays the image but in terminal I get several [ INFO:0@0.0nn] messages which says that loading libraries failed.

Failed-messages in terminal:

```
[ INFO:0@0.050] global c:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\highgui\src\registry.impl.hpp (114) cv::highgui_backend::UIBackendRegistry::UIBackendRegistry UI: Enabled backends(4, sorted by priority): GTK(1000); GTK3(990); GTK2(980); WIN32(970) + BUILTIN(WIN32UI)
[ INFO:0@0.052] global c:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\core\src\utils\plugin_loader.impl.hpp (67) cv::plugin::impl::DynamicLib::libraryLoad load C:\Users\username\opencv\build\x64\vc15\bin\opencv_highgui_gtk460_64.dll => FAILED
[ INFO:0@0.056] global c:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\core\src\utils\plugin_loader.impl.hpp (67) cv::plugin::impl::DynamicLib::libraryLoad load opencv_highgui_gtk460_64.dll => FAILED
[ INFO:0@0.058] global c:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\core\src\utils\plugin_loader.impl.hpp (67) cv::plugin::impl::DynamicLib::libraryLoad load C:\Users\username\opencv\build\x64\vc15\bin\opencv_highgui_gtk3460_64.dll => FAILED
[ INFO:0@0.063] global c:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\core\src\utils\plugin_loader.impl.hpp (67) cv::plugin::impl::DynamicLib::libraryLoad load opencv_highgui_gtk3460_64.dll => FAILED
[ INFO:0@0.064] global c:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\core\src\utils\plugin_loader.impl.hpp (67) cv::plugin::impl::DynamicLib::libraryLoad load C:\Users\username\opencv\build\x64\vc15\bin\opencv_highgui_gtk2460_64.dll => FAILED
[ INFO:0@0.068] global c:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\core\src\utils\plugin_loader.impl.hpp (67) cv::plugin::impl::DynamicLib::libraryLoad load opencv_highgui_gtk2460_64.dll => FAILED
[ INFO:0@0.069] global c:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\highgui\src\backend.cpp (90) cv::highgui_backend::createUIBackend UI: using backend: WIN32 (priority=970)
[ INFO:0@0.071] global c:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window_w32.cpp (3013) cv::impl::Win32BackendUI::createWindow OpenCV/UI: Creating Win32UI window: Display Image (1)
[ INFO:0@0.111] global c:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\core\src\parallel\registry_parallel.impl.hpp (96) cv::parallel::ParallelBackendRegistry::ParallelBackendRegistry core(parallel): Enabled backends(3, sorted by priority): ONETBB(1000); TBB(990); OPENMP(980)
[ INFO:0@0.112] global c:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\core\src\utils\plugin_loader.impl.hpp (67) cv::plugin::impl::DynamicLib::libraryLoad load C:\Users\username\opencv\build\x64\vc15\bin\opencv_core_parallel_onetbb460_64d.dll => FAILED
[ INFO:0@0.117] global c:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\core\src\utils\plugin_loader.impl.hpp (67) cv::plugin::impl::DynamicLib::libraryLoad load opencv_core_parallel_onetbb460_64d.dll => FAILED
[ INFO:0@0.119] global c:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\core\src\utils\plugin_loader.impl.hpp (67) cv::plugin::impl::DynamicLib::libraryLoad load C:\Users\username\opencv\build\x64\vc15\bin\opencv_core_parallel_tbb460_64d.dll 
=> FAILED
[ INFO:0@0.125] global c:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\core\src\utils\plugin_loader.impl.hpp (67) cv::plugin::impl::DynamicLib::libraryLoad load opencv_core_parallel_tbb460_64d.dll => FAILED
[ INFO:0@0.126] global c:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\core\src\utils\plugin_loader.impl.hpp (67) cv::plugin::impl::DynamicLib::libraryLoad load C:\Users\username\opencv\build\x64\vc15\bin\opencv_core_parallel_openmp460_64d.dll => FAILED        
[ INFO:0@0.132] global c:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\core\src\utils\plugin_loader.impl.hpp (67) cv::plugin::impl::DynamicLib::libraryLoad load opencv_core_parallel_openmp460_64d.dll => FAILED
PS C:\Users\username\Desktop\testak\build\Debug> ."C:/Users/username/Desktop/testak/build/Debug/testak.exe"
[ INFO:0@0.064] global c:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\highgui\src\registry.impl.hpp (114) cv::highgui_backend::UIBackendRegistry::UIBackendRegistry UI: Enabled backends(4, sorted by priority): GTK(1000); GTK3(990); GTK2(980); WIN32(970) + BUILTIN(WIN32UI)
[ INFO:0@0.069] global c:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\core\src\utils\plugin_loader.impl.hpp (67) cv::plugin::impl::DynamicLib::libraryLoad load C:\Users\username\opencv\build\x64\vc15\bin\opencv_highgui_gtk460_64.dll => FAILED
[ INFO:0@0.085] global c:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\core\src\utils\plugin_loader.impl.hpp (67) cv::plugin::impl::DynamicLib::libraryLoad load opencv_highgui_gtk460_64.dll => FAILED
[ INFO:0@0.088] global c:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\core\src\utils\plugin_loader.impl.hpp (67) cv::plugin::impl::DynamicLib::libraryLoad load C:\Users\username\opencv\build\x64\vc15\bin\opencv_highgui_gtk3460_64.dll => FAILED
[ INFO:0@0.096] global c:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\core\src\utils\plugin_loader.impl.hpp (67) cv::plugin::impl::DynamicLib::libraryLoad load opencv_highgui_gtk3460_64.dll => FAILED
[ INFO:0@0.098] global c:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\core\src\utils\plugin_loader.impl.hpp (67) cv::plugin::impl::DynamicLib::libraryLoad load C:\Users\username\opencv\build\x64\vc15\bin\opencv_highgui_gtk2460_64.dll => FAILED
[ INFO:0@0.103] global c:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\core\src\utils\plugin_loader.impl.hpp (67) cv::plugin::impl::DynamicLib::libraryLoad load opencv_highgui_gtk2460_64.dll => FAILED
[ INFO:0@0.104] global c:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\highgui\src\backend.cpp (90) cv::highgui_backend::createUIBackend UI: using backend: WIN32 (priority=970)
[ INFO:0@0.106] global c:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window_w32.cpp (3013) cv::impl::Win32BackendUI::createWindow OpenCV/UI: Creating Win32UI window: Display Image (1)
[ INFO:0@0.172] global c:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\core\src\parallel\registry_parallel.impl.hpp (96) cv::parallel::ParallelBackendRegistry::ParallelBackendRegistry core(parallel): Enabled backends(3, sorted by priority): ONETBB(1000); TBB(990); OPENMP(980)
[ INFO:0@0.173] global c:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\core\src\utils\plugin_loader.impl.hpp (67) cv::plugin::impl::DynamicLib::libraryLoad load C:\Users\username\opencv\build\x64\vc15\bin\opencv_core_parallel_onetbb460_64d.dll => FAILED        
[ INFO:0@0.178] global c:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\core\src\utils\plugin_loader.impl.hpp (67) cv::plugin::impl::DynamicLib::libraryLoad load opencv_core_parallel_onetbb460_64d.dll => FAILED
[ INFO:0@0.180] global c:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\core\src\utils\plugin_loader.impl.hpp (67) cv::plugin::impl::DynamicLib::libraryLoad load C:\Users\username\opencv\build\x64\vc15\bin\opencv_core_parallel_tbb460_64d.dll => FAILED
[ INFO:0@0.185] global c:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\core\src\utils\plugin_loader.impl.hpp (67) cv::plugin::impl::DynamicLib::libraryLoad load opencv_core_parallel_tbb460_64d.dll => FAILED
[ INFO:0@0.186] global c:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\core\src\utils\plugin_loader.impl.hpp (67) cv::plugin::impl::DynamicLib::libraryLoad load C:\Users\username\opencv\build\x64\vc15\bin\opencv_core_parallel_openmp460_64d.dll => FAILED        
[ INFO:0@0.190] global c:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\core\src\utils\plugin_loader.impl.hpp (67) cv::plugin::impl::DynamicLib::libraryLoad load opencv_core_parallel_openmp460_64d.dll => FAILED
```

I am thinking if error could be in configuration .json files, CMakeLists.txt or something else. I would like to know why I get this messages and how to repair it.

Comment: is the architecture of your CPU 32 or 64 bits?

Comment: Are you using msvc as your compiler and not MinGW?

Comment: @stateMachine my CPU is  64-bits

Comment: @drescherjm yes, for this case I used msvc